# Is it appropriate for me as a landlord to make gifts to the minor children of my tenant if I believe it will make them happy or more successful?

Tags: mussar-ethics

I am landlord for a lady and her three minor children who rent a house I own next door to my residence. One of her children is a talented athlete who is on a local community football team.  Since the children's father no longer is living with them, this boy us now the man of the house, so to speak. I have found him to be very mannerly and agreeable when his mom asks him to help around the house and he has also helped me on several occasions. Even though he is only twelve years old, he is big and strong and quite capable and I feel like I would like to reward him.

Since he is the kicker for his team, as well as fullback and linebacker, and I have seen him in action, I thought that it would be great if I got him a regulation football and a kicking net, so that he could practice kicking at home. What I would include in my gift would probably cost less than two hundred dollars.

My wife believes that it is inappropriate for me to give him or the other children gifts of any kind, even though the tenants are my neighbors as well as my tenants. She says that these people are none of my business. I say that if I can make a child happy and encourage him to practice a skill that may make him more successful when he might compete to be the kicker on his future high school team, I would like to see that happen. I think this might also be a good lesson for the boy in 'paying it forward' encouraging the boy to look for opportunities in his future life to help others rather than seek to repay me for my gift to him.  I think my wife is wrong to discourage me from involving myself in the lives of my neighbors. What do my Jewish values say about my wanting to help my neighbors? By the way, I let my lady tenant know what I am doing and she approves of it.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Nukeguy and thanks for this first question. Your question will likely be closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us. Also can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?